Return status 405 for ALL undefined routes in NestJS
I'm trying to implement a global guards to return error 405 Method no allowed in NestJS. So far, I found this method but only apply to ExpressJS

You can extend the ExceptionFilter to intercept 404 errors and return 405:
import { ArgumentsHost, Catch, ExceptionFilter, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Response } from 'express';

@Catch()
export class NestExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
    catch(exception: any, host: ArgumentsHost): void {
        const context = host.switchToHttp();
        const response = context.getResponse<Response>();

        if (exception.status === HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) {
            response.status(HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED).send();
        } else {
            response.status(exception.getStatus()).send();
        }
    }
}

then, in you main @Module you can add it as a provider:
providers: [
    { provide: APP_FILTER, useClass: NestExceptionFilter }
]

